# How can we change a category's extension in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We would like to know, how can we change the category extension. Our Old website is developed in with (.htm, .php and .html) extension, Now we transfer it into wordpress. so it can be possible to make the category post in .html, .htm and .php according to the category. We have high pagerank on these pages, we would not able to delete or change the extention ... so please suggest me, how can we do this in wordpress.

Thanks & Regards

ROD

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to modify the category URL using [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), however from an organic perspective it makes sense to use a 301 redirect in your .htaccess file. Even Google officially recommends 301 redirects and hence the link juice will eventually flow to your new pages.

This way, you retain the page rank and evolve your URL structure too.

Comment: Could please tell me how to use this function in wordpress. We have several, categories which need to be use .php and .htm extension.

Comment: What is the current category URL like and what would you want it to be like?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Redirection" plugin in wordpress to create 301 redirects for all the pages you need